# How I can show my empty records (one to many relationship is there) in access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

Sorry for the inconvenience. I am new to MS Access and I have created two tables i.e "Catagories" and "Contacts". Both tables have one to many relationship please see the ERD [ERD click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRxGR.png).

I have populated some data in the tables but still some categories are not filled. Now I want to show those categories with no record in categories table.

[Please see this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggzSl.png) maybe this will clear you what I am saying.

If you anyone can help that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Please learn how to ask a proper question:  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I have edited the question please see

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all categories even if they don't have contacts associated, than you have to right click above the relationship line and in the context menu choose "Edit Relationship" and in the window dialog which opens find the button "Join Type" on the right side and click, in the next window dialog choose "Include ALL records from 'Category' and only those records from 'Contacts' where the joined fields are equal."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking when you say `categories with no record in categories table` - do you mean data in the `Contacts.Category` column which do not exist in the `Categories.ID` column?  If so, it can be done with an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT Con.* 
FROM Contacts Con
LEFT JOIN Categories Cat ON Con.Category = Cat.ID
WHERE Cat.ID IS NULL
```

This will show all the records in the `Contacts` table that are using a category that doesn't exist in the `Categores` table.

Comment: Thanks it's working but also I need to show the category name in which the record ID fall

Comment: So this is where I'm unclear of what you need.  The query I posted shows the Contacts whose category doesn't exist in the Categories table, so there is no category name to display.  If you're wanting to show Categories that aren't being used in contacts, you'd flip the `JOIN` criteria like `LEFT JOIN Categories Cat ON Cat.ID = Con.Category WHERE Con.Category IS NULL` and you'd select `Cat.*`